# BUG - TableView with strange size and not showing scroll indicators

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, scroll

I do not remember the first time I saw this bug. If it started with the iOS 9 framework or not.

The problem is when I have an UITableView as first child of my UIViewController in Storyboard the tableView apparently have a bigger content size and do not show the scroll indicators. When I put a transparent UIView as first child, the problem disappear.

The same issue occurs with UITableViewControllers. And there is no trick because de TableView is the main View of the ViewController.

Anyone got this bug too or know how to fix it?

I am trying to resolve this problem in order to prevent future problems just because the Storyboard is in "MacGyver mode".

Comment: Is the UITableView inside of a UIView in your UIViewController or is it the root view? Also, are you using AutoLayout?

Comment: Check tableview's frame. Probably its bigger than screensize or superview. Is it ?

Comment: Guys, yes I am using auto layout.
The problem is, when  I put a tableview as first child of viewcontroller.view, the bug appears. If the ONLY difference is any view in the same hierarchy level of the tableview behind it, i. e., if my tableview is not the index 0 child,  everything goes ok.

The same occurs with UITableVIewController. However, I do not found a trick to workaround it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the frame of the table view is bigger than the screen size. That's why no scrolling indicators appear. When you add a transparent view as the superview of your table view, you're somehow influencing the resizing of that table view. Try inspecting the frame of the table view and then play around with its layout constraints.

Update:
I've taken the PO's code and found out that (on iPhone 6 simulator) the table view has frame = (0 0; 375 667) and contentSize: {600, 0}. This is the answer why no scrolling indicators appear. The content size is "wrong" because no data source has been specified. 
And then, when I specified a data source and returned 28 for row count on section 0, I got an exception. That exception said: "failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource". That was because `UITableViewCell *cell = [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];` returned nil (that was expected BTW). The right way of instantiating table view cells is this:

```
 - (__kindofUITableViewCell * _Nullable)dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:(NSString * _Nonnull)identifier
```

... but it's a completely different story. Hope this helps.

Comment: No man, I am not adding a transparent view as the parent of my tableview.
What I need to do to solve the bug is to put a view in the same hierarchy level of my tableview, however, as first child.
If the tableview is the child of index 0 of the viewcontroller.view the bug appears.

Comment: That's strange. Could you share the code you're dealing with? Or a sample "buggy" project?

Comment: I don't no why but I created another simple project and the behavior is quite normal.

However, this code shows what I am doing with a static tableview. I am just modifying font and stuffs like that. 
https://snipt.net/embed/9292acef4e7fb1c747af187f1b2a099e/

The code is very much simple. Just 5 lines of real code.
My project was created using xCode 6 and now I am using xCode 7. This could be the cause? Because the project I created here from the scratch works.

Comment: Every time you update Xcode, you get "phantom" issues. BTW, the snippet is shown as js+HTML code :)

Comment: I've got a question about UITableViewCell *cell = [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; Did you subclass SettingsViewController from UITableViewController?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91410/discussion-between-arthur-gevorkyan-and-swallace).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was occurring because in some point of the project an `UITabBar` of `UITabBarController` was override and the bottom layout guide was affected. Now, I just hide the native tab bar and put the views that I need on top of it. In this case, the native Tab Bar still there, hidden but there, so the layout guides.